# Twenty Thirteen HTML version mobile menu error

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress-theming

I have used twenty thirteen wordpress theme for a html page. It is working in normal windows. I have simply copy paste the code and replace necessary css and js files.

But in the mobile mode the mein manu doesnt toggle on-of...

I have searched some pages and and try to find a solution but i cannot achieve this.

I have added

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("ul").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

in the header and

add this in the as menu toggle button;

```
<h3 class="menu-toggle"><button id="hide">Menü</button></h3>
```

It has start to toggle but it has used main menu. But the orginal wp themes shows a customised sublevelled menu.

How can i do that.

Regards

Comment: Instead of button click do `#hide` click

Comment: can u show that in the code... i ll will be very glad.

Comment: i have checked but it is same. im using firefox and the wordpress working without an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#hide").click(function(){
     $("ul#menu-menu-1").toggle(); // try to specify the class or ID of ul
   });
});
```

Comment: i have copy that code block and replaced with my script but it is not toggled now.

my code is like this. 

<div class="menu-menu-1-container">
<ul id="menu-menu-1" class="nav-menu"> 

I have changed "ul" to "menu-menu-1" and it is stil does not toggle too.

Comment: I have redo again. now it is toggled and worked but the orginal file shows submenus and this one is not. But however it is working. Thanks for your effort. 

But if you can have look at that page in mobile mode menu is showed with submenus but mine is not for now...

btw thanks again. you saved my night...

Comment: i ll have look the why it doesnt save the customized menu tomorrow. Thanks again.